# How to tell whether a linux tcp socket had recent activity?

Tags: linux, linux-networking, kernel, socket, netstat

Most of the time, when changing or upgrading a network service, I would do this during maintenance hours but some services are rarely used so it is tempting to just check whether it is currently in use and if not, take it down for a minute or five.

Some service may not have an access log or I might just be too lazy to check it.

Is there a way to check whether there has been recent activity on its tcp network socket? Is there a command that shows when a connection was last used?